# Autowired and Qualifier java annotations

Tags: java, spring

I have a problem with this annotations.

This is my Circle class:

```
public class Circle implements Shape {

    private Point center;

    public Point getCenter() {
        return center;
    }

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("circleRelated")
    public void setCenter(Point center) {
        this.center = center;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw() {
        System.out.println("Drawing cicrle " + center.getX() + ", " + center.getY());
    }
}
```

This is my spring.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="pointA" class="com.majewski.javabrains.Point">
        <qualifier value="circleRelated" />
        <property name="x" value ="0" />
        <property name="y" value ="0" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="pointB" class="com.majewski.javabrains.Point">
        <property name="x" value ="0" />
        <property name="y" value ="1" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="pointC" class="com.majewski.javabrains.Point">
        <property name="x" value ="0" />
        <property name="y" value ="20" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="circle" class="com.majewski.javabrains.Circle" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

</beans>
```

And this is my main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        AbstractApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
        context.registerShutdownHook();

        Shape shape = (Shape) context.getBean("circle");
        shape.draw();
    }
```

And I am getting an error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'circle': Injection of autowired dependencies
    failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: 
    public void com.majewski.javabrains.Circle.setCenter(com.majewski.javabrains.Point);
    nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.majewski.javabrains.Point] is defined:
    expected single matching bean but found 3: pointA,pointB,pointC
```

I've added the  tab in my "pointA" bean so i do not understand what is wrong with my program. Can someone explain it to me?

Comment: Are you sure about the package name?

Comment: Try using bean id (pointA) in the Cicle qualifier annotation

Comment: It gives the same error with "pointA" in Qualifier and it works fine when I comment out pointB and pointC

Comment: You don't have a bean called `"circleRelated"`. Only beans `pointA`, `pointB`, and `pointC`

Comment: @Stewart I don't want to use this names so I am using <qualifier>

Comment: Then where is the bean? It has to exist!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i suppose you are missing

```
<context:annotation-config  />
```

in your spring-context XML and `@Qualifier("circleRelated")` is ignored because of that.

--- edit ---

of course, in order to use that you need to extend your namespace definitions ...

```
<beans 
    ...
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    ...
  xsi:schemaLocation=".... http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-YOUR-SPRING-VERSION-HERE.xsd">
```

Comment: Now I am getting this error: "The prefix "context" for element "context:annotation-config" is not bound."

Comment: @KrzysztofMajewski i edited the answer ... you need to declare the 'context' namespace using 'xmlns' and 'xsi:schemaLocation' ...

Comment: This is my new .xml header: <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-YOUR-SPRING-VERSION-HERE.xsd"> And I am getting error that those location cannot be found

Comment: Failed to read schema document 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-YOUR-SPRING-VERSION-HERE.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.

Comment: OMG I am so stupid. Didn't notice YOUR_VERSIOn xD Sorry

Comment: @KrzysztofMajewski ;-)

Answer (score 1):

well the problem is in the qualifier `@Qualifier("circleRelated")` , because you try to bind a bean with name circleRelated but in your spring-conf.xml you have declared only 3 points with names : pointA , pointB , pointC , so it cannot match and inject the instance , so either change the `@Qualifier("circleRelated")` to `@Qualifier("pointA")` or declare a bean in the xml with `<bean id="circleRelated" class="com.majewski.javabrains.Point">`

Comment: @AntJavaDev probably not, because the Bean that is supposed to be injected is qualified in the xml using <qualifier value="circleRelated" /> ... probably  the Qualifier ANNOTATION is ignored because Springs annotation configuration is not set up.

Comment: @AndréR. , i got your point , you are right he is missing the <context:annotation-config  /> , otherwise he has to manage the wiring in the xml

Comment: KrzysztofMajewski your @Autowired annotations are being ignored , because in your spring-conf.xml you are missing the tag <context:annotation-config  /> as in AndréR's Answer , the proper configuration would be something like   <bean id="circle" class="com.majewski.javabrains.Circle" />
<property name="center" ref="pointA"/></bean>